# Odd SQL Error - No printing out

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a rather odd error on my hands and I can't figure it out. I've tried debugging by changing the values of $username to the real values and it displays the results fine, i've echoed the SQL query out to see what values are being passed through and it's all correct, however no result is displayed.

Any ideas? Thank you

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username1, username2 FROM friends WHERE username1 = '$username' OR username2 = '$username' AND friends >= 2") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "<p>".$row['username1']."</p>";
}
```

Comment: may be something like `or ( username2 = '$username' AND friends >= 2)`

Comment: have dumped the sql string and ran it in mysql to see if you get the expected results  ?

Comment: use brackets in your where condition & "like" operator

Comment: @OliverBS Yes I have, it works perfectly

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I've tried that, still nothing

Comment: if you've taken what's in $sql and tried in DB and it works fine.  then you're getting an error that you're not trapping for.  Either you don't have an open connection, connecting to the wrong db (Test vs dev or prod), you're trapping for the error but not checking the state. after.  Is Php throwing an error?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't take care of precedence of `AND` over `OR`. You need to add parenthesis.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username1, username2 " . 
                   "FROM friends " .
                   "WHERE ( username1 = '$username' OR username2 = '$username' ) AND friends >= 2") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "<p>".$row['username1']."</p>";
}
```

Comment: using `where '$username' IN (username2, username2) AND (friends >= 2)` would also have worked. though would still be subject to the same problem if more terms were added.